# Need help styling jScrollPane

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane

I am trying to style my [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com)

but I find that my scroll bar is extending out of the container

[image]

How can I fix it? Code can be seen in http://jsfiddle.net/Mfest/

Comment: @it looks correct to me,but you can go to jscrollpane code and change the height and all,i used jscroll panel long back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### My answer is now redundant, [see the below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134047/need-help-styling-jscrollpane/5217594#5217594).

---

I don't know the "proper jScrollPane method", but this does work in modern browsers.

The problem is that the `padding` and `border` on `.jspTrack` is adding up to make the height of the scrollbar `306px`, instead of `300px`.

So, you can use the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing) property on `.jspTrack`:

```
    /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing */
    width: 12px; /* adjust width */
    /* support Firefox, Safari/WebKit, Opera and IE8 */
   -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:        border-box;
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Mfest/2/

I would personally not be satisfied with this answer, because it seems a kludgy way to fix it.

Comment: In my opinion, the plugin should handle this issue.

Comment: Thanks work like a charm but with some reset css, it breaks again, why is that? http://img4.imageshack.us/i/66035853.jpg/

Comment: @jiewmeng: Without reset: http://jsfiddle.net/Mfest/2/ With reset: http://jsfiddle.net/Mfest/5/ - they both look the same, so it's nothing to do with the reset. I just didn't notice that it looks wrong when you scroll down when I wrote my answer in the first place. Sorry :( I could have another look at this later if you'd like.

Comment: thanks, I'll also try to fix it, I think it has to do with the plugin not calculating the right dimensions ... I have a feeling setting options may help, I'll check that ltr

Comment: This does seem kinda kludgey but will work. I've just added the officially recommended solution below which is to use the "caps" that the plugin provides...

Answer (score 3):

The recommended solution is to use the .jspCap to add space above or below the track rather than padding or borders. I've implemented this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mfest/6/

Note that I set the top and bottom caps to different sizes to make things appear to line up equally - I think that the rounded corners/ borders may be confusing the jScrollPane calculations a little bit.

Another demo of the caps in action:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/caps.html

Comment: +1 and I linked your answer from mine to make it obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you have `padding:2px;` for `.jspTrack` this add padding for top and bottom of scrollbar, with result to overflow the container. Try to change it to `padding:0 2px;`.

*Update:* I set fixed heights for `.jspTrack` and `.jspDrag` also.

**Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/Mfest/3/

Comment: Yours has exactly the same problem as the original. The scroll bar should have a rounded border at the bottom, and that's not visible in your fiddle.

Comment: @Poinity you are right. The border also affect the result. I updated the demo.